# Is it possible to hide 'Full Site' option from left side menu of Salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app, navigation

We need to hide the full site option from left side menu. Is it possible?

Comment: Answer would be No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot hide "Full Site" option in Salesforce. However your scenario would be that you don't want users to see Visualforce pages in Web mode. In that case you can use browser detection technique on visualforce pages.

Something like that:

```
public class MyController {

 public MyController() {
 }

 public PageReference redirect() {
  String userAgent =
  ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('USER-AGENT');

  if(userAgent.contains('iPhone')) {
   PageReference pr = Page.iPhoneFriendlyPage;
   pr.setRedirect(true);
   return pr;
  }
  return null;
 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Ashwani, I will try your method. We wanted to hide that option in iOS and Android clients.